# Has the documentary hypothesis become invalid?

Tags: history, religion, bible, catholic-church, christianity

[The documentary hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentary_hypothesis) is a hypothesis which proposes  that the Pentateuch (the first five books of the Bible) was derived from originally independent, parallel and complete narratives, which were subsequently combined into the current form by a series of redactors.After R.N. Whybry's book [The Making of the Pentateuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Making_of_the_Pentateuch) the support for the documentary hypothesis [has been weakened.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentary_hypothesis#Weakening_of_support) and numerous other models have been proposed. However, has the documentary hypothesis completely refuted as per the [apologetic claims](http://creation.com/debunking-the-documentary-hypothesis) ? (Another criticism can be found [here](http://www.biblearchaeology.org/post/2010/09/24/the-documentary-hypothesis.aspx) )Even if documentary hypothesis is invalid, does it imply that Moses is really author of Pentateuch and King David is author of Psalms ? (I have not asked this on Mi Yodeya or Christianity Stack exchange as it is for "committed" Jews and Christians respectively. )

Comment: You don't have to be a Christian to answer questions on the Christianity site. However it might be a bit of a borderline question there, and also on the other main candidate Biblical Hermeneutics.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) What sort of evidence in an answer would convince you either way? This seems a much more appropriate question for Hermeneutics.SE, where biblical scholars hang out.

Comment: I did not know where should I ask the question but now I will ask this question in Biblical Hermeneutics.Thanks!

Comment: If you reworked the question to "what are the arguments against the documentary hypothesis?" then it would be a pretty good question on Christianity.SE. You could also ask the reverse question: what are the arguments for it. Mi Yodeya would likely not accept it in either form. The parts about any conclusions implying the Moses is really the author is more of a different question. I think Biblical Hermeneutics is open to authorship questions, so this might work there.